# get old JWT token after PC restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt

I have a small MERN project, where people can "log in / sign up", all know that after "log in / sign up" we save a token in a cookie, but after the PC restart I don't have the old JWT token, which means I should "log in / sign up" again, I want to the user have JWT token until it logs out from website

I don't know what I can do, I tried googling but I can't find an answer

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: Actualy it has nothing to do with your pc, it's more complex. When you store your token, you have to create a  middleware in your front that will get the token from the cookies and send a request to verify this token. Watch tutos on youtube, it will be easier

Comment: Maybe you can save your token to local storage ?